# Imacros copy and paste from box

Tags: imacros

im using imacros I want to do a copy from
`<div class="captcha-w">43959</div>`

then paste it to captcha box (TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT=43959)

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:43959
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT=43959
```

I want to copy the captcha code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "typical" use case for the [`EXTRACT` Command/Mechanism](https://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#EXTRACT):

```js
'Extract Captcha:
'TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:43959 // (Recorded)
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"captcha-w"&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

'Paste Captcha into Input Field:
'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT=43959 // (Recorded)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER ATTR=ID:captcha CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
```

I can't be sure about the `TAG POS=1` for the Extract without being able to test on the Page/Site; if that's not correct, you may have to try with `TAG POS=2`, `TAG POS=3`, etc..., or to use '[Relative Positioning](https://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction#Extract_with_Relative_Positioning)' to lower the `POS` Value to "R1".